# Unable to access functions from another class (C# Windows Form, SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm learning database connectivity using C# Windows Form Application in Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio.

The problem I'm having is I'm unable to access the *AddParams()* and *sqlQueryCmd()* functions from the *SQLConn.cs* Class.
I've tried changing the access modifiers from private to public but it didn't work. Can anyone guide me here? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**SQLConn.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace dbConnectivityTest1
{
    public class SQLConn
    {
        public static void Main1(string[] args)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection("Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=UserID;\r\nPassword=Password;"))
            {
                List<SqlParameter> paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();
                string AddParams(string tableName, object insVal)
                {
                    SqlParameter sqlparams = new SqlParameter(tableName, insVal);
                    paramList.Add(sqlparams);
                }
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

                string sqlQueryCmd(string sqlQuery)
                {
                    int recordCount = 0;
                    string excptnShow = "";

                    try
                    {
                        connString.Open();
                        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connString);
                        paramList.ForEach(p => { sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(p); });
                        paramList.Clear();
                        DataTable sqlDT = new DataTable();
                        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                        recordCount = sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        excptnShow = "Error: \r\n" + ex.Message;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (connString.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            connString.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace dbConnectivityTest1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private SQLConn sqlDB = new SQLConn();

        private void enterNametextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            enterNametextBox.Clear();
        }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while(fullNameTextBox.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your Full Name!", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            while(contactTextBox.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your Contact Number!", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            while(ageTextBox.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your Age!", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            while(emailTextBox.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your E-mail!", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex emailRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$");
            while(!emailRegex.IsMatch(emailTextBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid E-mail!", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            InsVal();
        }

        public void InsVal()
        {
            **I am trying to call the SQLConn.cs Functions here**
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those functions are local in Main method. You should move them to class outside of Main function

Comment: And make them public...

Comment: Should I make a class outside the Main1 function and add these functions to that class or should I simply cut the functions from the Main1 function and paste them outside the Main1 function?

Comment: Learn how to [work with classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes), for working with data look at using [EF Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) for validation consider [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html).  EF Core makes working with data easier, FluentValidation validating data easier with rules for property in a [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031209/model-class-and-pojo-class#:~:text=A%20model%20class%20is%20typically%20used%20to%20%22model%22%20the%20data%20in%20your%20application).

Comment: Thank you so much for the links and advice. I was actually looking for the classes section of C#. I've just started learning C# coming from Visual Basic so Some of it is kinda new to me.

Comment: Yeah,
I did try it and while the SQLConn.cs program worked, I'm still unable to insert values from the form to my DB. Should I change the status of this thread to answered and generate a new thread if my new problem isn't resolved or should I keep this thread unanswered till the required output isn't achieved? 
I want to exploit all my resources of research and find a solution on my own before I post about it on this forum so that might take a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Movint addParam method/function would not solve the problem since the SqlParam variable is not available in sqlConn class.
the better approach for your goal is to to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace dbConnectivityTest1
{
public class SQLConn
{

    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private List<SqlParameter> _paramList;
    public SQLConn()
    {
        _connectionString="Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=UserID;\r\nPassword=Password;";
        _paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();
    }

    public void AddParams(string tableName, object insVal)
    {
        SqlParameter sqlparams = new SqlParameter(tableName, insVal);
        _paramList.Add(sqlparams);
    }

    public void sqlQueryCmd(string sqlQuery)
    {
        using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {

            int recordCount = 0;
            string excptnShow = "";

            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
                _paramList.ForEach(p => { sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(p); });
                _paramList.Clear();
                DataTable sqlDT = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                recordCount = sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                excptnShow = "Error: \r\n" + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    sqlConn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

in this scenario there is no need for Main method since every application can have only one Main method and winForms by default already have one Main method.

secondly, the SQLConn class can have private field of type List,
and a public method called AddParam which its responsibility is to add new params to it.

Lastly, a public SqlQueryCmd method is added to do the rest of the job.

you can now use this class to execute your query like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sqlConn = new SQLConn();

        sqlConn.AddParams("tableName","your Object");
        sqlConn.AddParams("tableName","your Object");
        sqlConn.AddParams("tableName","your Object");

        sqlConn.sqlQueryCmd("Query");
    }
```

Comment: Awesome,
I'll try this one out.

Thank You so much for the help, Sir. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried it and it works perfectly, I'm able to reference functions from the SQLConn.cs class however I have run into a new problem, now my data entered from the Form1.cs file doesn't get inserted into my DB. It's giving me an error: 
**A connection was successfully established with the server but then an error occurred during the login process

The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted**

I'm trying to resolve this one on my own. If I am unable to I'll post here again. Hopefully I won't have to.